# how to know on which button user made click?

Tags: android, button, expandablelistview

I have `ExpandableListView` and I have button on each group of this `ListView`. How to know on which group's button user made click?
Is it possible to give some id to buttons and edit texts and get this id when user did some event on those widgets?

Comment: You could always use setId() and getId() on a view object based on the position in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set an id for the buttons in your `listView_layout`. 
You need to set an `Adapter` for your listView. In the `getChildView` method you can set click listener for your button.

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

   @Override
   public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listView_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.mButton= (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myButton);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
   }

   public static class ViewHolder {
      public ImageButton mButton;
   }
}
```

Comment: Brother, it's expandable listView, You will not get getView method in that.

Comment: Brother, I meant getChildView.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
yourListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);
```

In the overridden method:

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

    switch (groupPosition or childPosition) {
    case 0:
        // do your logic
        break;

    default:
        break;

    }

    return false;
}
```

you will get both GroupPosition and ChildPosition.